# IsSerializable not in WinRT

Tags: serialization, windows-runtime

In **.Net** when we whant to check if a type is serializable we can do:

```
typeof(T).IsSerializable
```

MSDN documentation corresponding:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.type.isserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But **IsSerializable** doesn't exist in **WinRT**, so how can we check if a type is serializable or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the TypeInfo class. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.typeinfo(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh535795(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Thanks Kris it works. Here is the code for WinRT: `typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().IsSerializable`